# Using Fancybox with images larger than the viewport

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using the FancyBox plugin for a site that will be delivered on a touchscreen. Some functionality calls for allowing the user to 'zoom' in to a picture which is much larger than the viewport.

I'd like for the following to happen:

-The user should be able to scroll around the picture (scrollbars ok) but at the moment, I cannot get the horizontal scroll bar to show (the vertical one does).

You can see the functionality at [this link](http://evanmrose.co/projects/dev/mediacombo/public) if you click on the page then click on "indigenous traditions" and finally, click on "zoom and explore" below the photo.

Are there other plugins that might accomplish the same end without the hassle?

Comment: I just don't see why you'd want scroll bars at all?  Everything is set to fit within the viewport and the only way you get the scroll bars in general is by pinch zooming so they already know the space they're in.

Comment: I have the fittoView set to false meaning the image will pop up in full size as it should. The image is much larger than the viewport and as such you need to scroll to navigate the image. The issue is there is a vertical scrollbar and no horizontal one for some reason

Comment: This plugin seems really broken. I'm not sure what you've been testing in but I just tested in Firefox and half of the site doesn't work. The two properties I would assume are affecting your plugin the most are **OVERFLOW** and the sizing, being, more than incredibly off. I'll keep an eye out for a better plugin and let you know if I find anything, but certainly make sure you've browser tested on all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! Yeah the site is only half built. Testing certain views before implementing a CMS

Comment: @EvanM.Rose : your site is running in quirks mode. You have to separate the `DOCTYPE` from the `html` opening tag since they are two different elements in your document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Give a class name to your image element. For example,

```
<a class="fancybox" href="path/to/123.png">Picture</a>
```

At the very bottom of jquery.fancybox.js, type the following codes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        width: 1200
    });
});
```

It works on my website. You can change the width as you wish. Hope it helps!